# How do I get the index of each item in a groupby object in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I use groupby on a dataframe based on the columns I want and then I have to take the index of each item in its group. By index I mean, if there are 10 items in a group, the index goes from 0 to 9, not the dataframe index.

My code for doing this is below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 11, 10 ** 3), 'B': np.random.randint(0, 11, 10 ** 3), 
                   'C': np.random.randint(0, 11, 10 ** 3), 'D': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10 ** 3)})

grouped_by = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])
groups = dict(list(grouped_by))
index_dict = {k: v.index.tolist() for k,v in groups.items()}
df["POS"] = df.apply(lambda x: index_dict[(x["A"], x["B"], x["C"])].index(x.name), axis=1)
```

The dataframe here is just an example.

Is there a way to use the `grouped_by` to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using `cumcount()` on a dummy variable to generate a item index for each group.  It should be significantly faster too.

```
In [122]: df['dummy'] = 0
     ...: df["POS"] = df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['dummy'].cumcount()
     ...: df = df.drop('dummy', axis=1)
```

As @unutbu noted, even cleaner just to use:

```
df["POS"] = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).cumcount()
```

Comment: can you put them into a matrix or a nested list?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the index.

```
df_group.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The items maintain the same index from the parent data frame so even when you groupby, the index is still the same.

When you iterate, reset the index before iterating through the items in the group.

[Reset Index Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)